# New line inside color area

Tags: math-mode, color, line-breaking

I'm trying to enter new line inside colour area like this

```
$\color[rgb]{0,0,1}{P(A) = a +\newline b +\newline c +\newline d}$
```

But it does not work, why? And how do I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please, could you show us what you actually want to achieve? It seems to me like that `$...$` is not the right thing you should use, but we can't know.

Comment: The result I need is in the answer below. I needed for a, b, c to be written on different lines

Comment: Plus `\color` does not take two mandatory arguments`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not break lines inside `{}` groups in math. remove the spurious group and it works as intended:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

$\color[rgb]{0,0,1} P(A) = a +\newline b +\newline c +\newline d$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't break lines inside `{...}` group (which you used). Without the braces, the equation breaks (See David's answer). But to beautify, i.e. to align them neatly you may need the help from `amsmath` package and the environments it provides. For details, run `texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt/terminal. You can also check in the help menu of your tex editor for `texdoc`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}
  $\color[rgb]{0,0,1}
    P(A) = \!\begin{aligned}[t]
     a {}+{}\\
     b {}+{} \\
     c {}+{} \\
     d {}+{}
    \end{aligned}
  $
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can break lines inside `$` but not inside `{}` groups (which the OP had)

Comment: previous comment gone:-)